# Lighttpd sending wrong headers for UTF-8 content

Tags: utf-8, lighttpd

Ubuntu/Lighttpd is not serving my UTF-8 encoded files with the correct `Content-Type` header. It's sending `Content-Type: text/html` rather than `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. How do I configure Lighttpd to send the correct headers?

I didn't see any useful settings in the default `lighttpd.conf` and am having trouble finding information in the [documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default `lighttpd.conf` file seems to load MIME types from `/etc/mime.types` using a perl script:

```
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
```

In my `/etc/mime.types` my `html` files had been set to be served as `text/html`. I commented out the `include_shell` perl script and added the following [mimetype.assign](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Mimetype.assignDetails) entry to `lighttpd.conf`:

```
mimetype.assign = ( ".html" => "text/html; charset=utf-8" )
```

I'm not sure if there's a more elegant solution. Using this method I would need to copy in all of the entries in `/etc/mime.types` to retain the other MIME type mappings.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the very same problem and [finally found a solution on a blog](http://www.spieleplanet.eu/blogpost.php?t=47361)

Basically it's a pimped version of above mentioned perl script that adds the charset=utf-8 declaration to all mime-types that start with "text/"
Just replace the perl script and restart lighttpd.

Comment: This solution is more elegant, the Michael Dudley solution is not satisfying as its  either copying statically all the content or lacking mimetypes for all non-html data …

Answer (score 0):

It isn't cleaner to just add the `; charset=utf-8 string´ for each "text/" line in mimes.conf? I mean like:

```
  ".css"          =>      "text/css; charset=utf-8",
  ".html"         =>      "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  ...
```